# Does Python calculate list comprehension condition in each step?

Tags: python, optimization

In a list comprehension with a condition that has a function call in it, does Python (specifically CPython 3.9.4) call the function each time, or does it calculate the value once and then uses it?

For example if you have:

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
list_2 = [x for x in list_1 if x > np.average(list_1)]
```

Will Python actually calculate the `np.average(list_1)` `len(list_1)` times? So would it be more optimized to write

```
list_1 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
np_avg = np.average(list_1)
list_2 = [x for x in list_1 if x > np_avg]
```

instead? Or does Python already "know" to just calculate the average beforehand?

Comment: It will call it each time, in CPython at least.

Comment: "Python" has multiple implementations, aside from the versioning (the reference implementation CPython; Jython; IronPython; etc.). They may do different things.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I updated my post to specify the latest reference version you can get on pyhton.org. Btw. "they *may* do different things" I understand they *may*, but do they actually?

Comment: Try it yourself: `[x for x in range(5) if x is not print("yep")]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming standard CPython - Short answer: Yes. Your second snippet is more efficient.

A function call in the filter part of a list comprehension will be called for each element.

We can test this quite easily with a trivial example:

```
def f(value):
    """ Allow even values only """ 
    print('function called')
    return value % 2 == 0

mylist = [x for x in range(5) if f(x)]
# 'function called' will be printed 5 times
```

The above is somewhat equivalent to doing:

```
mylist = []
for x in range(5):
    if f(x):
        mylist.append(x)
```

Since you're comparing against the same average each time, you can indeed just calculate it beforehand and use the same value as you did in your second code snippet.

Answer (score 2):

Python *has* to call the function each time. It cannot optimize that part, because successive calls of the function *might* return different results (for example because of side effects). There is no easy way for Python’s compiler to be sure that this can’t happen.

Therefore, if you (the programmer) know that the result will always be the same – like in this case – it is probably advisable to calculate the result of the function in advance and use it inside the list comprehension.